# What's the composition of the Harvest?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, secret-invasion

In the Secret Invasion TV series, We see that Gravik is after the mystery item called Harvest.

> In the show, It is revealed that Fury had sent Skrulls to gather Avengers'DNA after the events of End Game.

> What is all the Avengers' DNA collected in the Harvest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the season finale, we are shown the list of DNA available in the Harvest on the computer screen when Gravik loads it into the Machine:

1. Ghost
2. Captain America
3. Corvus Glaive
4. Thanos
5. Outriders
6. Proxima Midnight
7. Captain Marvel
8. The Abomination
9. Mantis
10. Cull Obsidian
11. Drax
12. Korg
13. Ebony Maw
14. Frost Beast
15. Hulk
16. Chitauri
17. Valkyrie
18. Thor Odinson
19. Gamora
20. Flora Colossus (also known as Groot)
21. Winter Soldier

Comment: And from this, we seemingly learn that, for example, Ebony Maw's telekenesis powers, and Captain Marvel's glowy-Space-Stone powers, are somehow derived from their genes.

Comment: Or at the very least their DNA has been changed rather than always having the powers potential.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I mean, her powers come from being full of unlimited Space Stone energy. It might have changed her DNA, but it's does not make much sense that you can get the energy of the Infinity Gems just by having the same genetic code as someone else who has that energy. That's like collecting the DNA from a dehydrated person and making a clone who is permanently dehydrated.

Comment: And that is just the start. You also have people like Drax, Valkyrie, and Gamora. Sure, they are from super-strong species, but super-strong like a gorilla (or less). Their real lethality comes from their combat training. Does DNA carry that, too? Thor is the God of Thunder, but his sister is the God of Death. Is godhood genetic? Did he get the "thunder and lightning" gene, while she got the "making knives appear" gene (and the "draws strength from Asgard" gene)?